# Clip CCSprite/CCNode with another CCSprite/CCNode - Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, clipping, spritebuilder

I can clip using native coding within iOS however, as I wish to port across to Android using SpriteBuilder I want to clip 2 CCSprites using Cocos2D.

I am looking to do the following :

[image]

I have seen libraries which support only Cocos2D 2 however I am using the latest version and these no longer seem to work.

How would I achieve this affect?

Comment: Is this a cocos2d question ? if yes, show your code, what you tried, and what does not work for you ... if it is a Spritebuilder question dont tag cocos2d.

Comment: Cocos2D question. I can't find the library I tried but was for Cocos2d V 2... I know of Stencil but not sure how to apply it to this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a similar fix the following is native to Cocos2D.

```
//Get Screen size
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] viewSize];

//Set Clipping Sprite
    CCSprite *heroClip = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"stamina/MenuHappinessWhite.png"];
    heroClip.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2); // Middle of screen

//Set Sprite below Clipping
    CCSprite *heroUnder = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"stamina/MenuLevel.png"];
    heroUnder.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    heroUnder.scaleY = 0.5f;

    // Create Clipping Node
    CCClippingNode *scissor = [CCClippingNode clippingNodeWithStencil:heroClip];
    [scissor setContentSize:self.contentSize];
    [scissor setPositionType:CCPositionTypeNormalized];

    [scissor setAlphaThreshold:0.0];

    //[scissor setInverted:YES];
    [self addChild:scissor];

    // Add nodes to Clipping Node
    [scissor addChild:heroUnder];
```

and add this to app delegate

```
   //Load Clipping Mask
    [cocos2dSetup setObject:@GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES forKey:CCSetupDepthFormat];
```